# How do I set different file associations for .fon and .exe files, if both have the same MIME type?

Tags: mime-type

I sometimes need work with `.fon` bitmap font files.

When I try to set a default application for them (using the GUI), it also changes the application for `.exe` files, and vice versa. But I'm trying to associate two different applications with those (a font editor for `.fon`, and Wine for `.exe`).

The MIME type for both appears to be `application/x-ms-dos-executable`.

`file` identifies those `.fon` files as `MS-DOS executable, NE for MS Windows 3.x (DLL or font)`. "NE executable" appears to be an outdated format, so considering any NE executable a font (as opposed to PE) would be a reasonable tradeoff, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to register a new MIME type for `.fon` files into the MIME database:

- First, create an **XML file** in `/usr/share/mime/packages`:

  ```
  sudo nano /usr/share/mime/packages/ms-fon.xml
  ```
- Copy these lines into the file (use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste into `nano` window):

  ```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
     <mime-type type="application/x-ms-fon">
       <comment>Windows FON file</comment>
       <generic-icon name="font-x-generic"/>
       <glob pattern="*.fon"/>
     </mime-type>
  </mime-info>
  ```
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit `nano` and return to the terminal.
- Finally, update the MIME database:

  ```
  sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
  ```

Now the MIME type for your `.fon` files will be `application/x-ms-fon` while that for `.exe` files remains the same. You should be able to associate different applications with those types now.

**Reference**: https://developer.gnome.org/documentation/guidelines/maintainer/integrating.html#mime-types

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! The only thing I changed is using a shorter comment, since it's displayed in my file manager next to every font file.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I see, I didn't notice because I set my file manager to not display any information beneath icon names :). I wanted it to be descriptive but I guess that's a bit too long.

Comment: [This is how it looks for me](https://imgur.com/90QUsf7.png). The `FON font` on the right is the string I used.

Comment: Nice! I'm using Nemo and it shows up in **Detailed Type** while using List View. Guess I will shorten the `<comment>` value in my answer. Thanks for the follow-up!

Comment: Can the XML file not be also installed in `~/.local/share/mime`?

Comment: I found `xdg-mime install`, which may or may not be a more official way of doing this.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Confirmed. An XML file like above can be created anywhere, e.g. `~/Documents/ms-fon.xml`, and installed with: `xdg-mime install ~/Documents/ms-fon.xml`. The XML file will be copied to `~/.local/share/mime/packages`. Since this doesn't require root privilege, I think it's more preferable. You might want to add a dedicated answer for it :).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to create a .desktop file, for which a template is as below. This answer will focus on creating a default mime for a ".exe":

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=My Program
Exec=/path/to/myprogram %f
MimeType=application/x-ms-dos-executable;more_mimetypes_here_if_you_want
```

Use the xdg-mime from the xdg-tools, which implements the official standard as so:

`xdg-mime default mydesktopfile.desktop application/x-ms-dos-executable`

Comment: This is not an alternative to the other answer, but can be used after it, to associate the freshly created mimetype with an app. But the same thing can be done easily from the GUI (at least in Xfce, this is just RMB->Open With, I think). Good to know, nontheless.